# Get composite parts components using recursive cte SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

Good day! There is a table in which the components of the car are stored. A car consists of component parts and each detail may consist of its firm. At the exit, I want to get a list of all used details. To do this, I want to use the recursive CTE. Nessing level is not known in advance. But I can not understand how to implement it.

For example:

```
+---------+--------------+-----+--------------+
| main ID |     Name     | cID |  Component   |
+---------+--------------+-----+--------------+
|       1 | Car          |  11 | Engine       |
|       1 | Car          |  12 | Transmission |
|       1 | Car          |  13 | Body         |
|      11 | Engine       |  21 | Crankshaft   |
|      11 | Engine       |  22 | Piston       |
|      11 | Engine       |  23 | Valve        |
|      12 | Transmission |  31 | Carter       |
|      12 | Transmission |  32 | Differential |
|      12 | Transmission |  33 | Lead shaft   |
+---------+--------------+-----+--------------+
```

Following I want to get a list:

```
+---------------+
|  Components   |
+---------------+
| Engine        |
| Crankshaft    |
| Piston        |
| Valve         |
| Transmission  |
| Carter        |
| Differential  |
| Lead shaft    |
| Body          |
+---------------+
```

Please do not judge strictly - this is my first experience using recursive CTE

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh, MS SQL SERVER

Comment: I would start by normalizing your database design. You have redundancy there that can get messy.

Comment: @The Impaler, Unfortunately, the structure of the table cannot be changed, because It is created by third-party software manufacturers and works with this software. Have to work with what is

Answer (score 0):

You can walk the graph in multiple levels by using a recursive CTE, as you mention.

For example:

```
with
n as (
  select component, '/' || cid as path 
  from t 
  where main_id not in (select cid from t)
 union all
  select t.component, n.path || cid from n join t on t.main_id = n.cid
)
select component
from n
order by path
```

This is just an example. You can add more columns as needed, and tweak the starting nodes (by modifying the anchor member) or the walk path (by modifying the recursive member).